# Why the "custom setting button" of "ibus input method :: Bopomofo" is grey?

Tags: ibus

I‘ve just installed the ibus input method, and I chose Bopomofo as my default.

But why the **"custom setting button"** of **"ibus input method::Bopomofo"** is grey?

(I've seen some snapshots from Internet, but theirs are not grey.)

[image]

**PS.** The button where my cursor put is **"custom setting button (偏好設定)"**